# asp.net send get request to api and get json result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I send 'get' request from the server to API and get result with json data?
I heard about HTTPClient in .net 4.5 maybe there is something like that in .net 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For older Framework version You can use either [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which is really simple class for downloading/uploading data, or use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). WebRequest is lower level, but You can define method(GET,POST), UserAgent etc. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) You can find example about using WebRequest to do POST.

If You just want to get returned JSON from adress, WebClient should be sufficent.